# Bit Manipulation in c using & operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

What is the difference between the following two lines:

```
x & ~(1<<n) //line 1
x & ~(~0<<n) //line 2
```

Where x and n are integers. The above line of code finds the last n bits of x.
For ex: for x=107, n=5 line 1 produces 75 as output and line 2 produces 11.

Comment: `1` is `000...001` in binary. `~0` is `111...111`.

Comment: Have you tried e.g. the values of 0 to 16 and compared the values? Did you try on paper? What kind of differences are you asking about, in the face of obviously different results?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't declare the type of `x` in your question. By assuming it is of `signed` `integer` type. for e.g

```
int x = 107, n = 5; /* default type of int is signed */
```

**Case 1 :-** If `x=107` and `n=5` and you are performing `x & ~(1<<n)`

```
 1      =>  0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0001
1<<5    =>  0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0010 0000
           MSB                                          LSB 
---------------------------------------------------------
~(1<<5) =>  1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 1101 1111 
                                                        &
 x      =>  0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0110 1011
---------------------------------------------------------
        =>  0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0100 1011 => 64 + 8 + 2 + 1 => 75
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**Case 2 :-** If `x=107` and `n=5` and you are performing `x & ~(~0<<n)`

```
     0      => 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000
    ~0      => 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 
    ~0 << 5 => 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 | 1110 0000
    --------------------------------------------------------
              MSB                                          LSB
   ~(~0 <<5)=> 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0001 1111 
                                                           &
    x       => 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0110 1011
    --------------------------------------------------------
           =>  0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 1011 => 8 + 2 + 1 =>11
    --------------------------------------------------------
```

I assume you are aware of `bitwise AND(&)`, bitwise compliment (`~`) operator. Truth table of `&` is below. While performing any bitwise `&` with two operand just follow the below truth table.

```
--------------
A B |  A & B |
-------------|
0 0 |    0   |
0 1 |    0   |
1 0 |    0   |
1 1 |    1   |
```

And finally you are telling *The above line of code finds the last n bits of x ?* I don't think so above two line are doing that.